# Get only part of the message and reload only one div

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

this is an ajax method that inserts the data into a db and should supposedly display the new content.

```
      <script type = "text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {

                $('#submit').live('click', function(eve) {

                    eve.preventDefault() ; 

                    var form_data = {

                        title: $('#title').val()

                    };


                    $.ajax({

                    url: "http://localhost/ci/index.php/chat/comment",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: form_data,
                    success: function(msg) {



                            alert(msg);


                    }


                    });





                });


        });

    </script>
```

However in my /chat/comment, i am loading the view again, i.e, user submits a comment, load the view again and the comment should be there. My response from server is the view's HTML. However the view comes with all the divs and there are many of them. I need to retrieve only part of the div, say, #commentspace from the ajax on success.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [jQuery `$.load()` function](http://api.jquery.com/load/)?

### Example

Inside "firstpage.html"

```
$('#content').load('secondpage.html #content');
```

Comment: Description: Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element | i can already do that but i want only to load a specific part of data from the server. Say a whole html page is returned as HTML, how do i get only one div from it?

Comment: Something like this (but this is not right) 

$("#commentspace").html(msg).$('#commentspace');

Comment: Re-read the documentation. Loading Page Fragments - api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments